# An AutoSuggest that returns matches as HTML Form elements and not as JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have built a simple search tool for my Web App to search through my client database. It returns form submit buttons in a dropdown so that, when a selection is made, the selected clients ID is passed in a POST to the following page. The following page receives this POST and populates with all of the stored information about that client. This works the way I need it to for the most part, but I have a couple questions.

1) most autocompletes/autosuggests that I have seen examples of return JSON data as the results. Is using JSON inherently a smoother or safer process for this?

2) my search results (form buttons) display in a dropdown but are not navigable via TAB or ARROW keys. What is needed to add this accessibility? I tried to add TabIndex to the buttons but that did nothing.

I arrived at this particular solution for my need of a search function after failing miserably to understand some of the pre-packaged Autocomplete solutions out there. They seemed much more complex than what I needed for this Web App.

Here is what I am using.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">

        <input onKeyUp="myFunction()" type="text" id="searchterm" placeholder="Search for existing client">

        <div class="searchResults" id="results"></div>
        <script>document.getElementById("results").style.visibility='hidden';</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/watchdog.js"></script>

    </div>  
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("searchterm").value;

        if (input && input.length >= 2) {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchengine.php",
            data: {input : input},

                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {


            document.getElementById("results").style.visibility='visible';
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;
                }
                else {
                document.getElementById("results").style.visibility='hidden';
                }
            }

        }); 
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("results").style.visibility='hidden';
        return false;
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
include ('connect.php');

$input = trim($_POST['input']);
$input = htmlspecialchars($input);
$equiv = '%' . $input . '%';

// prepare stmt, bind param, execute
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id, firstname, lastname, city, state FROM client WHERE firstname LIKE ? OR lastname LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $equiv, $equiv);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($client_id, $firstname, $lastname, $city, $state);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo "
                <form name=\"clientSearchResults\" action=\"client.php\" method=\"post\">

                    <input name=\"client_id\" value=\"$client_id\" type=\"hidden\">
                    <div class=\"wrapper\">
                        <input style=\"height: 25px;\" type=\"submit\" value=\"$firstname $lastname - $city, $state\"></input>  
                    </div>

                </form>
            ";
        }

// close statement
$stmt->close();

include ('disconnect.php');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Re: TAB key access to submit buttons.

Looking into this further I found the answer to the accessability issue here:

[submit-button-not-focused-even-though-tabindex-is-properly-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334580/submit-button-not-focused-even-though-tabindex-is-properly-set)

This seems to be an issue I encountered because of my laptop being a Mac.